# ModalBottomSheetLayout disable clicking on the back

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use ModalBottomSheetLayout and I want the back part to darken when opening the lower curtain and it was not clickable. How to do it?

If you set screen Color = Color.Unspecified, the background will not be clickable, but at the same time it will be colorless. It doesn't suit me.

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ForpostScreen(forpostViewModel: ForpostViewModel = koinViewModel()) {

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val bottomSheetOpen = remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
    val viewState = forpostViewModel.forpostViewState.observeAsState()
    val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
    )

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(500.dp)) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.botton_sheet_top_line),
                    contentDescription = "Линия",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(20.dp)
                        .width(70.dp)
                        .padding(top = 10.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                )
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.all_cams_button),
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.title_text_color),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(600),
                    fontSize = 25.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 30.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                )
            }

        },
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 25.dp, topEnd = 25.dp),
        sheetElevation = 12.dp,
    ) {
        Surface(color = Color.White) {
            Column {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        bottomSheetOpen.value = true
                        scope.launch {
                            bottomSheetState.show()
                        }
                    },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(colorResource(id = R.color.button_color)),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 20.dp, start = 20.dp)
                        .height(30.dp)
                        .width(130.dp),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 0.dp),
                    content = {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.all_cams_button),
                            color = Color.White,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight(400)
                        )
                    }
                )

                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 50.dp, start = 20.dp),
                    text = "Репина, 1 Б",
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.title_text_color),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    letterSpacing= 1.sp
                )

                ButtonsLazyColumn(
                    listItem = listOf("Двор", "Подъезд", "Парковка", "Въезд", "Пост охраны"),
                    height = 50,
                    modifierPaddingStart = 20,
                    modifierPaddingTop = 15,
                    modifierPaddingEnd = 10,
                )

                Surface(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 20.dp)
                    .height(220.dp)
                    .background(Color.Black)) {
                    when (viewState.value) {
                        is ForpostViewState.Loading -> { VideoLoadingView() }
                        is ForpostViewState.Load -> { PlayerView(forpostViewModel = forpostViewModel) }
                        else -> {}
                    }
                }

                Divider(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 100.dp),
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.sevstar_gray_light),
                    thickness = 1.dp
                )

                ButtonsLazyColumn(
                    listItem = listOf("1 сек", "1 мин", "5 мин", "10 мин", "30 мин"),
                    height = 50,
                    modifierPaddingStart = 20,
                    modifierPaddingTop = 15,
                    modifierPaddingEnd = 10
                )

                Divider(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp),
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.sevstar_purple),
                    thickness = 1.dp
                )
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(
                    color = if (bottomSheetOpen.value) Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                    else Color.Transparent
                ))
    }

    if (bottomSheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden
        && bottomSheetState.offset.value > 1800) bottomSheetOpen.value = false

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = viewState, block = {
        forpostViewModel.obtainEvent(event = ForpostEvents.EnterScreen)
    })
}
```

I made the back darkening myself and it works, but in this case the back part becomes clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
  initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
  confirmStateChange = {false}
)
```

and you have to manually close the bottom sheet like,

```
onClick = { scope.launch { bottomSheetState.hide() } }
```

Comment: In this case, swipe closure does not work.